# python: datetime.strptime gives "does not match format" error

Tags: python, datetime, format

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
start_time = datetime.strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z", "2017-07-19 09:00:00-0700")
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
ValueError: time data '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z' does not match format '2017-07-19 09:00:00-0700'
```

This is the webpage I used as reference:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

After looking at this code multiple times, I can't seem to notice the error at all. This is very much a second pair of eyes needed situation. Thanks for any help you can give, everyone.

Comment: The actual problem is that you interchanged the date and the format.

Comment: `datetime.strptime("2017-07-19 09:00:00-0700", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")`